# I get Error when I exit my app

Tags: android, surfaceview

the error is the following:
"unfortunately, myAppname has sopped."

I am Making a game in SurfaceView and using many bitmaps and sounds.
My question is; what could be causing this error? I have Atopd() and released() the sounds, when i exit. There is a thread that is running, I dont know if I have to kill it or not and if so, how?. The bitmaps are still loaded when I exit, do i have to release them not and if so, how?

I tried posting image of error in DDMS, but it seems i dont have enough poins to place an image...thats funny.

**ddms says;

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2009): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3207
E/AndroidRuntime(2009): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at com.example.spaceinvaders.MainActivity$GameView.onDraw(MainActivity.java:478)
E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at com.example.spaceinvaders.GameLogic.run(GameLogic.java:68)**
```

***Line 68 in Game Logic calls; this.mGameView.onDraw(canvas);
Line 478 in Main Activity is: canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(38, 132, 3));***

This is the GameLogic class :

```
public class GameLogic extends Thread 
{
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private GameView mGameView;
    private int game_state;
    public static final int PAUSE = 0;
    public static final int READY = 1;
    public static final int RUNNING = 2;

    public GameLogic(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GameView mGameView) 
    {
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.mGameView = mGameView;
    }

    public void setGameState(int gamestate) 
    {
        this.game_state = gamestate;
    }

    public int getGameState()
    {
        return game_state;
    }


    @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        Canvas canvas;

        while (game_state == RUNNING) 
        {
            canvas = null;


            try 
            {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                long time_orig =System.currentTimeMillis();
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) 
                {
                    //this.mGameView.update();
                    //this.mGameView.onDraw(canvas);
                    try 
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(10);//(4);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e1) 
                    {
                    }

                    long time_interim = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    int adj_mov = (int)(time_interim - time_orig);
                    mGameView.update(adj_mov);
                    time_orig = time_interim;
                    this.mGameView.onDraw(canvas);
                }
            }

            finally 
            {
                if (canvas != null) 
                {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the game works fine until i hit back button to exit.

@  Nobu Games:
1.) in MainActivity;

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
{
    mGameLogic.setGameState(GameLogic.PAUSE);
}
```

2.) in GameLogic

```
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(10);//(4);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e1) 
            {
            }

            long time_interim = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int adj_mov = (int)(time_interim - time_orig);
            mGameView.update(adj_mov);
            time_orig = time_interim;
            if(canvas != null)
                this.mGameView.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }

    finally 
    {
```

....
Problem persists. I thank you for your Time And Knowledge.

NOW it the log gives me this error:

```
04-17 15:08:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(16286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 15:08:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(16286): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.spaceinvaders/com.example.spaceinvaders.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
04-17 15:08:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
04-17 15:08:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3329)
04-17 15:08:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:134)
04-17 15:08:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266)
04-17 15:08:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 15:08:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 15:08:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4722)
04-17 15:08:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 15:08:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 15:08:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
04-17 15:08:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
04-17 15:08:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my first post and would like Thank You All for all the help you provide to beginners. LB

Comment: Post your code where error occurs. Post your logcat as well. That'll go a long way in helping us to help you out.

Comment: thats the proble, I dont knwo wgere the error is. I have over a thou lines of code...

Comment: The point of examining the logcat output is to determine where the error occurs, as well as its nature.

Comment: From your logcat, it probably happens at MainActivity.java, line 478 or GameLogic.java, line 68. please post the source code surrounding those areas.

Comment: Since you say that you do not explicitly stop "a thread", I assume that you are talking about your game loop thread (`GameLogic`). When your game activity stops you must make sure that the game loop thread is also properly stopped, before you release any resources or set any members to null.

Comment: OK @Nobu Games: I think we are headed in the right direction...How and where do I stop the game loop thread??

Comment: Can you post the `run` method of your `GameLogic` class? I assume that's your game loop that updates the game state, isn't it?

Comment: In order to stop your game loop you would need to call `gameLogic.setGameState(GameLogic.PAUSE);` for example (or any int value except for `RUNNING`) when your game activity stops (`Activity.onStop`). Also it is not guaranteed that `surfaceHolder.lockCanvas()` always returns a `Canvas` object. It can also return `null` when the surface is not ready to be drawn to (e.g. when your activity finishes). I believe this is what causes the `NullPointerException` in your case. Execute your draw update code only if `canvas` is not `null`.

Comment: Are you sure it's still the same error message you get after the changes?

Comment: yes. I have recompiled and tried it on my device. Error Persists. Could it be the bitmaps (sprites?)...

Comment: The `NullPointerException` you posted above is because of `canvas` being null when you call `onDraw`. Since you are checking that it is not null, this kind of baffles me now. I would assume that you are dealing with a different crash reason now. Do you know how to debug your app? https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: yes, i have debugged it and it works. When i Exit the Game and return it to Android OS the error comes up on my screen. I have stoped and released all sounds, but i am not sure Android device is happy with the Bitmaps...

Comment: He, yeah, that's a different error message now. Make sure to add `super.onDestroy();` to your `MainActivity`'s `onDestroy()` method. When you override any activity life cycle method such as `onCreate` or `onStart` you must also call the parent (aka 'super') class' implementation of the method you are overriding.

Comment: WoW. @Nobu Games. You Guys ARE AMAZING!!!I added this...  protected void onDestroy() {super.onDestroy();... And The problem RESIDED. All The books on android programming could not help me, and You DID. THANK YOU. We should make a game together the 3 of us... it would be better that candycrush....

Comment: It does not give me the error when I exit, but when i restart it does. Whats up with that???

Comment: how do i give Credit? Im new here. U deserve the credit indeed..

Comment: Here's the thing, I'm glad that I could help you out, however, this question changed a lot while we were trying to debug the original problem, so I feel it's a bit too cumbersome to write a good answer. Don't worry, I'm OK with not getting any credit here :-) ... you should also create a new question for your latest problem. This question here has way too much information in it by now. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you `@Override` the `onDestroy()` method then you have to call the `super.onDestroy()` method in `onDestroy()`.

```
android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.spaceinvaders/com.example.spaceinvaders.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
```

Comment: @Override, thank you, I overlked that. I have to keep Activity Lifecycles in mind.